# Mapping with two kind of key

Tags: solidity

I have some addresses and some strings which are denoted to some values and I must be able to retrieve the value associated with both keys. I guess I must create 2 separate mapping with each kind of keys but this is so ugly and I don't like it. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Please share some code, so that we can refer to your question more precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use address as primary key and map strings to addresses.  This way you will avoid storing value twice:

```
mapping (string => address) private stringsToAddresses;
mapping (address => Value) private addressesToValues;

function addValue (string memory s, address a, Value memory v) public {
    stringsToAddresses [s] = a;
    addressesToValues [a] = v;
}

function getValueByString (string memory s) public view returns (Value) {
    return addressesToValues [stringsToAddresses [s]];
}

function getValueByAddress (address a) public view returns (Value) {
    return addressesToValues [a];
}
```

Comment: Oh this is so smart and clean. Thank you.